# Superscript in pandoc epub not rendering on Kindle

Tags: pandoc, epub, kindle

I'm using markdown like the following to try and add superscript to my epub.

```markdown
1^st^
```

This produces an epub with the expected html `sup` tag.

But when I open it on my Kindle, there is no superscript.

[image: 1st]

Answer (score 0):

Using Kindle Create to produce an epub with superscript, it looks like a style is missing. I added this to pandoc's default css file (obtained via `pandoc --print-default-data-file epub.css`).

```css
sup {
  font-size: 0.6666667em;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

Using the modified css file (via `--css`) it renders correctly.

[image: 1st]